# How to make Vue.js and Thymeleaf exchange data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, thymeleaf

Given that `e` is a `Vue.js` data and I want to trigger on the click the url `/profile/someusername`.

```
<a th:href="@{/profile}">{{e.username}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some time on documentations. I have discovered the cleaner and better way to fix it.

```
<a v-bind:href="'/baseAppPath/profile/'e.username">{{e.username}}</a>
```

OR

```
<a :href="'/baseAppPath/profile/'e.username">{{e.username}}</a>
```